# Аналог grep -v для ansible

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, администрирование, ansible, jinja2

Нужно получить всех когда-либо входивших пользователей на винде. В списке не должно быть папки `Public`.

Такая конструкция не работает:

```
- name: TEST find 4 win
  block:
    - win_find:
        paths: C:\Users\
        file_type: directory
        excludes: Public
      register: win_find_out
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ win_find_out.files }}"
```

Есть ещё параметр `patterns`, но `!Public`, `?!Public` или `not (Public)` не работают - выхлоп вообще пропадает.

`ansible 2.7.5`

Comment: Чегото я не вижу `exlude` в доках. Есть `regexp` - патерн вроде такой будет `^.+(?!Public).+$` Поделись опытом работы ансибл и винды... может в чатике :)

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/7hwhSz/1

Comment: @Hellseher, есть в https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/find_module.html. Я как-то не подумал, что там может быть разная кодовая база для параметров.

Comment: @Hellseher, не, не прокатило. Вываливает Public. Что ты хочешь узнать и в каком именно чате тебе рассказать?

Comment: @Hellseher, ну, где вопросы-то?

Comment: Добавил вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/949887/

Comment: `^(?!.*Public)`  пробовали? Или `r'^(?!.*\\Public(?![^\\]))'`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, ААААААААААААААААААААААААА МАТЬТВАЮ!!!!!!!!!!! РАБОТАЕТ!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!111

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, оформляй как ответ! УРА!!!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, первый вариант проканал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать такое регулярное выражение:

```
^(?!.*Public)
```

См. [демо регулярного выражения онлайн](https://regex101.com/r/4Vo5nP/1).

**Подробности**

- `^` - начало строки
- `(?!.*Public)` - исключающий блок предварительного просмотра вперёд, который не вернёт совпадения, если сразу после текущей позиции имеется

  - `.*` - 0 и более символов, отличных от символа перевода на новую строку
  - `Public` - строка `Public`

Если в строке могут быть символы переноса строки, добавьте `(?s)` в начало:

```
(?s)^(?!.*Public)
```