# Быстрое развертывание Ansible на Windows хостах

Tags: ansible

Как проще и быстрей развернуть провизию через Ansible для Windows машин?

Для GNU/Linux это сводится к 3 шагам:

- добавить пользователя в sudo группу
- cгенерировать RSA ключь на управляющем хосте
- раскидать ключь по хостоам

Просмотрел соответствующую документацию но бьем предварительных "плясок с бубном" зашкалил за предел выделенного времени.

Comment: Ну чё, как успехи? Добрался потестить?

Answer (score 1):

### На Windows:

Скрипт запускать "от имени Администратора":

```
@echo on
:: Разрешаем пошику выполнять любые скрипты. Без цифровых подписей.
powershell Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted

:: Подстраховка взятая из https://windowsnotes.ru/powershell-2/nastrojka-udalennogo-vzaimodejstviya-v-powershell-chast-1/ .
powershell Enable-PSRemoting

:: А это уже моё. Опытным путём (15 часов убил. Это при том, что ДО этого всё работало) выяснил, что служба с отложенным запуском может подложить свинью и не запуститься. Надо принудительно менять на просто "Автоматически".
sc \\localhost config winrm start= auto

:: Разрешаем пинги
netsh firewall set icmpsetting 8

:: Разрешаем дефолтные порты винрм. Чтобы фаерволл не блочил
netsh firewall set portopening TCP 5985 ENABLE
netsh firewall set portopening TCP 5986 ENABLE

:: Шмагия взятая из https://www.dmosk.ru/instruktions.php?object=ansible-windows .
winrm quickconfig /quiet && winrm set winrm/config/client/auth @{Basic="true"} && winrm set winrm/config/service/auth @{Basic="true"} && winrm set winrm/config/service @{AllowUnencrypted="true"}

:: Это чисто посмотреть статус работы.
winrm enumerate winrm/config/listener
```

Для `Windows 7` дополнительно надо воткнуть `KB3191566`, который как раз добавляет `Windows Management Framework v5.1`. Для `W2k12` - `KB3191565`. [Скачать](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/powershell/wmf/5.1/install-configure).

**Про фаерволл.** Если сеть помечена как `общественная` - ansible работать не будет. Надо или сильно ковыряться в правилах или поменять статус на `частная`.

### На Linux:

```
sudo -i
add-apt-repository -y ppa:ansible/ansible
apt update
apt -y install ansible python-winrm
```

Файл `my-connection-options.yml` будет выглядеть так:

```
ansible_user: "sysadmin"
ansible_password: "qazwsxedc"

ansible_connection: "winrm"
ansible_winrm_scheme: "http"
ansible_port: "5985"
```