# Как из Linux запустить на другой машине powershell скрипт

Tags: linux, powershell

Есть машина с Sentos, есть Windows машина с powershell. Нужно по команде запускать с Centos на windows машине powershell скрипт. 
Если конкретней, на Centos крутится некий сайт с функционалом, в котором пользователь загружает фотографию, далее фотография появляется в некой папке (функционал сайта реализован на PHP и работает всё хорошо). Нужно что бы об этом (о загрузке фотографии) сразу узнал Powershell на другой windows машине, и кое что сделал с этой фотографией, для начала пусть бы он сказал "Загружена фотография". 
Но если еще проще, как из Linux инициировать запуск скрипта powershell на удаленной машине самыми разными способами? далее я сам уже додумаю :)

Comment: а что делает этот скрипт? как часто происходит это событие?

Comment: этот скрипт далее загружает фото в Active Directory

Comment: а это надо сделать отказоустойчиво? просто если не дернется скрипт по какой либо причине как быть?

Comment: Используйте powershell remoting

Comment: а если чуть побдробней? не совсем понял ?

Comment: -отказоустойчивость не нужна. если не дернится не страшно.

Comment: Ты прям про `ansible` рассказал: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/949971/191416

Comment: `ssh` сервер поднимите на Виндоуз машине.

Answer (score 0):

К примеру, на вин-машине поднять какой-нибудь веб-сервер, например apache, ну и php. После загрузки фотографии, php скрипт с линукс-машины обращается к win обычным http запросом, в котором и передаете свои параметры, ну а дальше php вызывает все, что надо с помощью exec

Answer (score 0):

Сам еще не пробовал, но возможно как вариант вам подойдет.
https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-core-on-linux?view=powershell-6

А там уже потом

Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {Restart-Service spooler} -ComputerName server1